# Counting cliques in adjacency matrices formed from blocks

Tags: graph-theory

I want to construct an adjacency matrix using blocks of smaller adjacency matrices. Assuming no self-loops, and that the represented graphs are undirected, I might construct an adjacency matrix of order 4 like this:

I start off with adjacency matrices representing $K_{2}$:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Then I fill in the entries of the bigger adjacency matrix with the values in these smaller adjacency matrices (in this case, there would be 4 "blocks"):
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

This new adjacency matrix is interesting, because even though I have filled in all of the blocks with $K_{2}$, the resulting adjacency matrix is not complete; it is not a $K_{4}$.

I'm wondering specifically about the how the clique count is affected by changing blocks: in the example above, if I change the block in the bottom-left quadrant to be a $\bar{K_{2}}$ (and update the corresponding block about the diagonal so that the matrix remains symmetric), how does the clique count change?
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

What is the language to ask about these types of constructions? If I knew the clique counts and sizes of the adjacency matrix I was modifying in this way, is there an efficient algorithm that allows me to update these values? (The naive algorithm would just be to enumerate all the cliques from scratch).

Comment: With your new matrix, the adjacency matrix is not symmetric, so it does not correspond to an undirected graph

Comment: By the way, you might find it interesting that your first construction can be characterized as the [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_graphs) of a self-looped $K_2$ with $K_2$.

Comment: Good catch that the new matrix wasn't symmetric. I've updated the post to make it so.

As for the tensor product, is there anything interesting about clique counting there? I'm aware of Hedetniemi's conjecture, so it looks like "properties on tensor products" is something that's studied, and clique counts are a basic property, but I wouldn't know the first place to look.